# Replace certain strings with value from former line

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have the following text:

```
Source IP,URL
1.1.1.1,example1.com
Blank,example2.com
2.2.2.2,example3.com
Blank,example4.com
Blank,example5.com
Blank,example6.com
Blank,example7.com
7.7.7.7,example8.com
Blank,example9.com
Blank,example10.com
```

How can i replace "Blank" with the the non-blank value above it and get the following output?

```
Source IP,URL
1.1.1.1,example1.com
1.1.1.1,example2.com
2.2.2.2,example3.com
2.2.2.2,example4.com
2.2.2.2,example5.com
2.2.2.2,example6.com
2.2.2.2,example7.com
7.7.7.7,example8.com
7.7.7.7,example9.com
7.7.7.7,example10.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Perl solution:

```
perl -pe ' $prev=$1 if /^([\d\.]+)/; s/Blank/$prev/' file.txt
```

Explanation:

- Perl's `-p` flag means "Go through the input file line by line and print each line", `-e` means "run the script given on the command line".
- `$prev=$1 if /^([\d\.]+)/;` : If the line starts with (`^`) a string of numbers (`\d`) and dots `\.`, save that string (the IP) as `$prev`. So, as the script reads the file, `$prev` will contain the last IP found.
- `s/Blank/$prev/` : Substitute the string `Blank` with the value of `$prev`.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, '{if ($1 == "Blank") ip=repltext; else {ip=$1; repltext=$1;};
  print ip "," $2}' inputfile
```

assuming that "Source IP,URL" is not part of the input. If it is change to

```
awk -F, 'NR == 1 {next;}; {if ($1 == "Blank") ...
```

Also assuming that the first data line does not contain "Blank" but always an IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idiomatic awk solution:

```
<infile awk '$1 == "Blank" { $1 = p } { p = $1 } 1' FS=, OFS=,
```

Output:

```
Source IP,URL
1.1.1.1,example1.com
1.1.1.1,example2.com
2.2.2.2,example3.com
2.2.2.2,example4.com
2.2.2.2,example5.com
2.2.2.2,example6.com
2.2.2.2,example7.com
7.7.7.7,example8.com
7.7.7.7,example9.com
7.7.7.7,example10.com
```